# Does repairing Windows with installation remove it from its current domain?

Tags: windows-xp, domain

I have a machine with Windows XP installed on it. It is also a member of a domain.

I need to repair Windows using the installation of the same copy of Windows XP. Does repairing with installation remove it from its current domain?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to repair your machine?

Unless until if machine got failures then you should either go for repair / reinstallation based on machine position.

As per my knowledge, it won't remove the member from domain.

Comment: I'm assuming he's repairing the machine cause it's broken.  Just a guess.